# Use initWithNibName with a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Below is an example of using initWithNibName with separate xib views:

```
TerminalViewController *ctrl = [[TerminalViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"ControllerView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ctrl.appDelegate = self;
viewCtrl = ctrl;
```

However i need to implement it with a storyboard UI layout. For 'initWithNibName' how can i point to a View in my storyboard:

i.e. :

```
    TerminalViewController *ctrl = [[TerminalViewController alloc]     
    initWithNibName:@"STORYBOARD.ControllerView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ctrl.appDelegate = self;
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can give the controller an `Identifier` in the storyboard and then use this...

```
[self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheIdentifier"];
```

Just to add to this...

When creating a `UIViewController` subclass from a xib file. If you have a class called `MyViewController` and a xib called `MyViewController.xib` then all you need to do is...

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

The system will then look for a xib file called `MyViewController.xib` and use that to init the object and only fallback to doing it in code if the xib file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

get storyboard instance with name of storyboard and set identifier to all scene and get the instance

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    MyNewViewController *myVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UIStoryboard *stryBoard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
TerminalViewController *ctrl = [stryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerView"];
```